# SQL Counter Help

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I need help with my stored procedure, Currently I have the stored procedure accept values and post those values to my database.  This is for a program that gives students a quiz and it records their answers and scores into the database.  I wanted to keep track of how many attempts a student has made on each quiz that they take.  I need a way to have like a counter for each student and for each quiz. This is my current stored procedure when I run it my database gives me this error    Error 170: Line 17: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.
I also tried doing a LAST() function but the database said that LAST() function was unrecognized.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].spRecordStudentScore
     @StudentNum            BIGINT,
     @TestID               BIGINT,
     @DateCompleted     DATETIME,
     @Score        FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Attempt int;

    SET @Attempt = 1;

    BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tbStudentScores WHERE fdStudent# = @StudentNum AND fdTestID = @TestID AND fdAttempt = @Attempt)
        SET @Attempt = 1;
    ELSE 
        SELECT @Attempt = fdAttempt FROM dbo.tbStudentScores WHERE fdStudent# = @StudentNum AND fdTestID = @TestID ORDER BY fdAttempt DESC LIMIT 1

    END

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
                  BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tbStudentScores WHERE fdStudent# = @StudentNum AND fdTestID = @TestID AND fdDateCompleted = @DateCompleted AND fdScore = @Score)

                     INSERT INTO dbo.tbStudentScores 
                                (fdStudent#,
             fdTestID,
             fdAttempt,
             fdDateCompleted,
             fdScore) 
                        VALUES (@StudentNum,
             @TestID,
             @Attempt,
             @DateCompleted,
             @Score) 
        END
                     -- END INSERT INTO dbo.tbStudentScores 

    IF @@error <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RETURN 1
        END

    ELSE
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
            RETURN 0
        END
END
-- END PROCEDURE [dbo].spRecordStudentScore
GO
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? It looks like SQL Server but you're using non-SQL Server syntax like `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to find the next attempt number, you don't need anything special -- here is the most basic sql for it:

DECLARE @Attempt int;

```
SELECT 
    @Attempt = isnull(max(fdAttempt),0)
FROM 
    dbo.tbStudentScores 
WHERE 
    fdStudent# = @StudentNum 
    AND fdTestID = @TestID
```

You can add a +1 to it before you do your next insert -- either:

```
SET @Attempt = @Attempt + 1
```

OR in the SELECT, just +1 it there

```
SELECT 
        @Attempt = isnull(max(fdAttempt),0) + 1
...
```

Comment: BTW -- the isnull part just takes care of cases where the student has not made an attempt yet.

Comment: Thank you this helped, and I saw that I forgot to increase my counter

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
SELECT @Attempt = fdAttempt FROM dbo.tbStudentScores WHERE fdStudent# = @StudentNum AND fdTestID = @TestID ORDER BY fdAttempt DESC LIMIT 1
```

with this

```
SELECT TOP 1 @Attempt = fdAttempt FROM dbo.tbStudentScores WHERE fdStudent# = @StudentNum AND fdTestID = @TestID ORDER BY fdAttempt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`SET @Attempt = SELECT TOP 1 fdAttempt FROM dbo.tbStudentScores WHERE fdStudent# = @StudentNum AND     fdTestID = @TestID ORDER BY fdAttempt DESC)`

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comments below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].spRecordStudentScore
     @StudentNum            BIGINT,
     @TestID               BIGINT,
     @DateCompleted     DATETIME,
     @Score        FLOAT
```

I see that `@Score` is defined as `FLOAT`... which would be an approximate value.  Are you sure that you wouldn't want to use a `DECIMAL` type instead?

Also, `BIGINT` seems rather large for a `TestID` or `StudentNum` (Unless `StudentNum` should really be a `VARCHAR`)... are you sure that `INT` wouldn't be sufficient?

```
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Attempt int;

    SET @Attempt = 1;

    BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tbStudentScores WHERE fdStudent# = @StudentNum AND fdTestID = @TestID AND fdAttempt = @Attempt)
        SET @Attempt = 1;
    ELSE 
        SELECT @Attempt = fdAttempt FROM dbo.tbStudentScores WHERE fdStudent# = @StudentNum AND fdTestID = @TestID ORDER BY fdAttempt DESC LIMIT 1

    END
```

Instead of `LIMIT 1`, you can do `SELECT TOP 1 @Attempt = fdAttempt`...

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
                  BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tbStudentScores WHERE fdStudent# = @StudentNum AND fdTestID = @TestID AND fdDateCompleted = @DateCompleted AND fdScore = @Score)
```

A record could actually sneak in here between the checking if it exists and prior to inserting it... if you needed to prevent this, you would need to use a serializable read... probably with an exclusive lock on the read as well to prevent a deadlock.  Or, a better idea would be to make sure that you have the appropriate unique constraint in place on the table.

```
                     INSERT INTO dbo.tbStudentScores 
                                (fdStudent#,
             fdTestID,
             fdAttempt,
             fdDateCompleted,
             fdScore) 
                        VALUES (@StudentNum,
             @TestID,
             @Attempt,
             @DateCompleted,
             @Score) 
        END
                     -- END INSERT INTO dbo.tbStudentScores
```

Which version of MS SQL Server are you using?  If it is 2005 or more recent, you should check out `TRY CATCH` blocks for error handling.

```
    IF @@error <> 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RETURN 1
        END

    ELSE
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
            RETURN 0
        END
END
-- END PROCEDURE [dbo].spRecordStudentScore
GO
```